# how to click a textbox which is actually a date picker using selenium python ? the HTML is attached below. image of the textbox is also attached

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker, textbox, hidden

[HTML for the Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWANj.png)

my code is
[Picture of text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSXgC.png)

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.